Upload errors logs only to DataDog with helm chart
I'm using ingress-nginx helm chart. the chart produce lots of logs around 1M in 1 hour.
In order to save costs, how can i limit the chart to upload only Error message.
I've set this in values.yml, however this not work and DataDog keep gets info logs.
controller:
  config:
    log-level: error


This looks like a question for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

You can do this with ConfigMap:
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.45.0
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.29.0
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
# ...

# Changed the empty data object below from
# data: {}

# To
data:
  error-log-level: error

Or, I am not sure, you can try this directly like this:
controller:
  config:
    error-log-level: error

Here you can read about it
